# How to multiply two arrays with each element as a digit c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int

I am going to have an array that is 50 elements long. Each element will contain one digit to form a 50 digit number. What I want to do is multiply this 50 digit long array by another 50 digit long array. The way I thought of doing this was converting each number to form one string. Then produce an algorithm that would multiply line by line 20 digits at a time. Then once the last for loop breaks out of scope, I could reconstruct the new array, digit by digit from converting it from a string. Any alternate ideas before I attempt this, or is what I got what you would do too?

Comment: We usually comment on code and not designs.  My advice is to think about how you would multiply two 50 digit numbers using paper and pencil.

Comment: Just remember that a string is effectively an array already, I don't think you should convert to a string first for this reason.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use an existing multi-precision arithmetic library?

Comment: boost cpp_int or other wont let me output or store number higher than 20 digits

Comment: @ shuttle, do you think a char array would be better?

Comment: If this is a practical problem and not a learning exercise I'd just use something like https://gmplib.org/. If it's a learning exercise you could use something like `uint8_t` to store each digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n1[50], n2[50], out[51];
// n1 and n2 must be populated here
int carry = 0;
for (int cur = 49; cur >= 0; --cur) {
  out[cur+1] = n1[cur] * n2[cur] + carry;
  carry = out[cur+1] / 10;
  out[cur+1] %= 10;
}
out[0] = carry;
```

Comment: I thought OP was asking for an NxN multiply not a digit by digit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could find the question at leetcode OJ named "Multiply Strings".
This is my solution. Just for reference. Wish this will help :)

```
class Solution {
public:
    string multiply(string num1, string num2) {
        int s1(num1.size()), s2(num2.size()), size(s1+s2);
        vector<int> digit(size,0), carry(size,0);  // digit: store current digit, carry: store carry digit
        for(int i = 0; i < s1; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < s2; ++j){
                int mul = num1[s1-1-i]-'0';
                int muled = num2[s2-1-j]-'0';
                int tmp = mul*muled;
                digit[size-1-i-j] += tmp%10;  // accum
                carry[size-1-i-j-1] += tmp/10;  // accum
            }
        }
        int carrFlag(0);  // initial carry_flag
        for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; --i){  // merge digit and carry
            int sum = digit[i] + carry[i] + carrFlag;
            ret.insert(ret.begin(),1,'0'+sum%10);  // compose result string
            carrFlag = sum/10;  // update carry_flag
        }
        int pos(0);
        while(ret[pos] == '0')  ++pos; // get rid of extra 0's
        if(pos>=size)    return "0";   // edge case
        return ret.substr(pos);
    }
private:
    string ret;
};
```